# Infer object shape from property value

Tags: typescript

Don't even know if this is possible, so here goes nothing...

```js
type CustomProps = {
    id: string;
    defaultValue: number;
}

function MyComponent(props: CustomProps){
    return <div>my custom fc</div>;
}

type Desired = {
    shape: React.ComponentType<any>
}

const x: Desired = {
    shape: MyComponent,
    // the issue is, to transform x on-the-fly
    // AFTER shape is declared
    // so it can extend the type of props MyComponent can receive
    // basically x becomes `Desired` & `CustomProps`
}
```

I know I can declare a type param for `Desired`, infer props, and that would make it work, but... it's not what i'm looking for.

This even possible?

Comment: Question is not clear for me

Comment: The question is mostly in the comments. The desired result is to have a dynamic type, that will take the shape of SomeProps, where SomeProps are inferred from the value of `shape`. I really don't know how to explain better